# Como colocar um JLabel acima dos botões num JDialog?

Tags: java, swing

Gostaria de colocar uma *label* num JDialog, mas acima dos botões lá existentes. Como posso fazer isso? Ficam-me todos os componentes em linha:

```
private void jFormattedNumMatriculaComercialMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                             

    JButton botaoSIM = new JButton("Sim");
    JButton botaoNAO = new JButton("Não");
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    JLabel mensagem = new JLabel("TESTE");

    botaoSIM.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jFormattedNumMatriculaComercial.setText(jFormattedNIPC.getText());
            jFormattedNumMatriculaComercial.setForeground(Color.black);
            jFormattedNumMatriculaComercial.requestFocus();
            dialog.dispose();
        }
    });

    botaoNAO.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            dialog.dispose();
        }
    });

    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.add(botaoSIM);
    content.add(botaoNAO);
    content.add(mensagem);

    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.getContentPane().add(content);
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

[image: PRINT JDIALOG]

**EDIT:** O Código está assim agora. Com o primeiro 'if' já resolvi a questão do abrir duas vezes a janela, mas ao carregar em não, eu pus a fazer requestFocus para outro campo mas aparece-me duas vezes:

```
private void jFormattedNumMatriculaComercialFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                                            
   if(jFormattedNumMatriculaComercial.getText().equals("         ")){ 
    if(jFormattedNIPC.getText().equals("         ")){}
    else{
    int opcao = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            "Número igual ao NIF/NIPC ?",
            "Número de Matrícula Comercial",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            new String[]{"Sim", "Não"}, 
            "default");

    if (opcao == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

        jFormattedNumMatriculaComercial.setText(jFormattedNIPC.getText());
        nomeOfContasC.requestFocus(); 

    } else {     nomeOfContasC.requestFocus();      
    }

    }
   }else {}

}
```

Comment: podes explicar para que propósito precisas disso? tipo qual a logica dessa operação?

Comment: Sim posso. Quero apenas uma janela que me mostre uma pergunta, e caso carregue em sim, ele realiza uma ação, caso clique em Não, realiza outra. Mas gostava do nome dos botões em Português e não o default do JOptionPane.

Comment: entao pelo que percebi se conseguisses mudar o nome dos botoes do joptionPane já nao precisavas de criar esse JDialog? certo?

Comment: Sim. O joptionPane que testei tinha 3 botões, o YES NO e CANCEL. Eu só preciso de um Sim e um Não, e uma pergunta, mais nada.

Comment: Suponho que sejas novo em programação, o teu código está um bocado confuso ;) contudo percebo te perfeitamente... Posso te dizer para ajudar é, os primeiros if's acho que podiam estar juntos, depois nao compares com os espaços vazios tentas comparar com o tamanho ou algo do genero fica mais visivel, depois sempre que queres sair da função que estás usa o 'return;'  assim vazio, isso faz com que saia automático da função.... Por **ultimo** sugiro que cries outra pergunta para isso, está a tirar o sentido a esta :)

Comment: Sim ainda sou novo a programar e safo-me como vou podendo e vou aprendendo com quem sabe, e por isso desde já o meu agradecimento :) A comparação com espaços vazios deve-se ao facto do campo conter máscara ######### e no fundo ela não está vazia. Se eu usar o isEmpty ele retorna false mesmo sem nada escrito! Obrigado !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para mudar os botões do `JoptionPane` podes usar este código:

```
    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
    "Aceitas este codigo como correto?", 
    "JoptionPane", 
    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
    null, 
    new String[]{"Sim aceito", "Não aceito"}, // this is the array
    "default");
```

*Resultado final:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**edit:**

Se precisas de verificar qual foi a resposta podes usar assim:

```
int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                "Aceitas este codigo como correto?",
                "JoptionPane",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                null,
                new String[]{"Sim aceito", "Não aceito"}, // this is the array
                "default");

        if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("Eu aceitei");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Nao!!! Eu nao aceito este codigo");
        }
```

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu queria. Só uma questão: Ao colocar esse código no campo de texto do OnFocusGain, ele aparece-me a jOptionPane duas vezes, como é que eu posso fechar a jOptionPane? o dispose(); fecha-me o programa todo. Desde já Obrigado!

Comment: percebi o que disseste mas não sei bem como te ajudar... 1º para fechar o programa todo é porque tens`setDefaultCloseOperation` nesse frame definido para fechar, altera para hide...(qualquer coisa)... Isso resolve te o problema de fechares o programa todo, agora o problema de o joptionPane aparecer 2 vezes é mais difícil porque ou em alguma parte do codigo chamas 2 vezes ou estas a executar uma função que o chama sem tu querer... Deu para perceber?

Comment: O meu código está exatamente igual à segunda sugestão que me deu. Se deixar como está, na opção 'Sim', fica-me um ciclo infinito de jOptionPane, porque o foco do campo não deve estar a sair. Desta forma, coloquei depois do System.out.println(), um nomeCampo.requestFocus(), e neste caso é que aparece a janela duas vezes :S Se em vez de colocar no método onFocusGain e puser o código no onMouseClick ele funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: faz um edit a tua pergunta e publica essa parte do código para ver se dá para perceber melhor, porque assim é difícil...